# What is the Space complexity in case of adding value to array?

Tags: java, algorithm

I want to ask about space complexity when creating an array or vector or any data structure; I understood that this data structure occupied space in memory when created it. But if then I loop over this data structure to insert value in every dimension of this array. Is it occupy another space or it consider put values in an array that already occupy space in memory. For example: let say create the following arrays which take space complexity `O(1)` because `size` is constant and creation these two arrays occupy constant space in memory:

```
    value1 = new double[size][size];
    value2 = new double[size][size];
```

then start to insert values in these arrays:

```
    Random ra = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {

            double g = ra.nextFloat();
            double h = ra.nextFloat();

            double m = (double) ((double) Math.round(g * 10) / 10.0);
            double n = (double) ((double) Math.round(h * 10) / 10.0);

            value1[i][j] = m;
            value2[i][j] = n;
```

I understood that i insert values in array which occupy space in memory and doesnt take another spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Primitive arrays don't require additional space after creation. However creating an empty `Object` array would reserve space only for the references. Creating the objects to put in the array would then take more memory for the individual objects themselves.

Comment: you mean that i need in this example O(n^2) in insert values to this two arrays. is it right?

Comment: Not in this example. If you had Objects you would need an additional `size*size*objectsize` space.

Comment: Ok, if i declared array like this :  double[][] value1; and not identify its length in declaration,  it occupy n space in memory or what and if i put values after that in program say 6 values only in this array. the space for that array become 6*8 bytes and then its space complexity for this array is O(1). is it right or not?

Comment: If you declare the array and never intialize it, it doesn't take any space. The initialized array takes `size*size` of space. If `size` is a constant, then it's constant space, if not you get `O(size²)`.

Comment: ,If i intialized it by null, it will occupy space or not.

Comment: That's not really initializing. Null is nothing.

Answer (score 0):

> when create array or vector or any data structure; i understood that this data structure occupied space in memory when created it.

Yes

> But if then i loop over this data structure to insert value in every dimension of this array. Is it occupy another space or it consider put values in array which already occupy space in memory.

As far as the array goes, there are no more allocations in your loop. And since your array is already for the `double` type, each cell has been allocated enough space to hold a `double` (8 bytes). However, it if were a `String` array or any other reference type, things would be different. The array would only hold the reference (the space for which was already allocated), but we'd need more space for the actual `String`.

> let say create the following arrays which take space complexity O(1) because size is constant and creation this two arrays occupy constant space in memory:

Whether `size` is constant depends on the question at hand. In many cases, I'd consider `size` to be `n` and therefore your array would be `O(n^2)`. In general, we say that a value is constant if its size doesn't depend on the size of the input. So if regardless of input, you'll always have an array with 100*100 elements, then it's `O(1)`.

Comment: Ok, i understood ;so if i have array of String like this:                                                     'String policy1 = "A B 1of2";  String policy3 = "A"; String policy5 = "A C 2of2";
    String policy7 = "A D 2of2";String policy2 = "A B 2of2";String policy4 = "A B 1of2 C D 1of2 1of2";String[] policies = {policy1, policy2, policy4,policy3, policy5, policy7};'

Comment: the length of the policies array is 6 and each object in it is string its space vary from one to another but still O(1) because each object identify its value . so the space for array policies is 6*O(!). Is it right?